# terraform try to install provider which is not described anywhere in modules or child modules

Tags: terraform

Below is my terraform init and terraform providers output. I did not even mention anywhere providers named "web" still it try to install. Also same module I'm not getting in output of "terraform -v"

```
haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$ terraform init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

- Using previously-installed hashicorp/local v1.4.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/tls v2.2.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.14.1
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/web...

Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/web: provider registry registry.terraform.io
does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/web

haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$ 
haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$ 
haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$


 
haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$ terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external] ~> 1.2
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local] ~> 1.4
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null] ~> 2.1
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random] ~> 2.2
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/web]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls] ~> 2.1



haresh@haresh:~/Downloads/cpinfra/terraform$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.13.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.14.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external v1.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v1.4.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v2.1.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v2.2.0
```

Comment: could you please share the terraform code

Answer (score 1):

If you search https://registry.terraform.io
The provider is not available for download.

If you did not specify it anywhere in your TF , please delete .terraform entirely and try to init again

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else was tried before. If you delete the .terraform folder and try again what do you get.